ngOninit do not execute in second rendering
I have a modal which is called when I click in a button, this is the modal logic:
export class SavedSearchesModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 constructor() {
     console.log('constructor');
 }
ngOnInit() {
         console.log('On init');
     }
ngOnDestroy() {
         console.log('On destroy');
     }
}

when I click the button the modal is opened and work fine, but when I navigate to another route and come back to the component which has the button to open the modal, and then open the modal again, this is the output result:
constructor

expected result:
constructor
On init

I applied this solution and it works fine:
constructor(private readonly cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    setTimeout(() => this.cdr.detectChanges(), 0);
    console.log('constructor');
}

but I do not want to manipulate the life cycle of the component, I consider this a bad practice
NOTE: I'm using angular material to manipulate the modal

Can you share more about this ? Like in a stackblitz example. There isn't enough code to tell you what you're wrong. You're right, you shouldn't have to call the CDR.

It's corrent that hook ngOnInit is initialized only once, from the example you show with the console log (read the doc https://angular.dev/guide/components/lifecycle#ngoninit).
It would be good to see the code, to understand the specific problem.
I can only make assumptions and maybe, using the modal reference, it is not invoked correctly or the reference does not invoke closure.
